# How to avoid Manual detectChanges in component

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I am getting an error, unless if i do not do the manual changes deduction with hook. how to avoid this? instead what hook should i use in this scenario?

here is my code:

```
import {
  Component,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  ComponentRef,
  ViewChild,
  ViewContainerRef,
  AfterViewInit,
  OnChanges,
  SimpleChanges,
  SimpleChange,
  AfterContentChecked,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges {
  @ViewChild('vrf', { read: ViewContainerRef }) vrf: ViewContainerRef;
  name = 'Angular';
  constructor(
    private containerFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('hi'); //not works
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const component =
      this.containerFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(HelloComponent);
    this.vrf.createComponent(component);
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gh2wnu?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ngAfterViewInit` is correct hook to mount the dynamic component. And the error you get is safe to ignore.

Comment: @Eldar can you update in sandbox, because i got the error as `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`, if I remove `this.cdr.detectChanges();` I do like to avoid it

Comment: Yes, what I mean when you remove the `detecChanges` `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` will occur and you can ignore that error.